# how to rotate line in fabricjs by clicking any point to select/drag?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I have a line with one end at a fixed point that can be rotated or stretched by the user.

jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bgnz21rs/)

It seems that in fabricJS the only way to select a line/object for rotation is the little selection box in the middle.  Also, a line is narrow so it is hard to select. Typically one must drag a rectangular selection box across the line to select it, then grab the unlabeled rotation box.

I want to simplify this to:  click anywhere on the line and drag to rotate.

ideas?

thx.

code snippet:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("c", {stateful: true});


var line1 = new fabric.Line([ 100, 200, 330, 200 ], {
      fill: 'red',
      stroke: 'red',
      strokeWidth: 3,
      selectable: true,
      evented: false,
      minScaleLimit: 0.25,
      lockRotation: false,
      centeredRotation: false,
      centeredScaling: false,

      originX: "left",    // origin of rotation/transformation.      
      originY: "bottom",    // origin of rotation/transformation.

      lockMovementX: true,
      lockMovementY: true,
      lockScalingFlip: true,
      lockScalingX: false,
      lockScalingY: false,
      lockSkewingX: false,
      lockSkewingY: false,
      lockUniScaling: true
    });
```

Comment: What's the reason behind setting `evented: false`?

Comment: just copy/pasted from an example. didn't think it important....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do what you need.

The idea is that on each `scale` event, we're going to rotate the line using fabric's internal `fabric.canvas._rotateObject()`, supplying it with current pointer's position. Then, immediately adjust the length of line to match the scale and reset the line's scale to 1.

This would be it, but while your example is relatively easy to do (the line is horizontal), it gets much trickier if you want to initialize a diagonal line. Imagine a line with `[0, 0, 100, 100]` as coordinates. This would render a rectangular 100x100 bounding box. You'd be able to rotate the line but the huge bounding box is obviously not something you want.

Because of that, we need to initialize the line as if it was rotated back to a horizontal position, then set an angle that it's supposed to have. To do that, we extend the built-in `fabric.Line` class and modify the constructor to make the calculations. And, since we already have new class, we're going to add the `scale` handler and default options into it as well. The constructor signature stays the same - `new fabric.RotatingLine([x1, y1, x2, y2], options)`, where `x1, y1` - fixed point, `x2, y2` - draggable tip.

Lastly, we're changing some of the properties. E.g. `evented: false` was the reason you couldn't select the line on click.

Below is the snippet with more comments, just in case.

```js
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas("c", {stateful: true})

fabric.RotatingLine = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Line, {
  minLength: 50, // we need to set this thing in px now
  
  initialize: function (points, options) {
    const a = new fabric.Point(points[0], points[1])
    const b = new fabric.Point(points[2], points[3])
    // find this line's vector
    const vectorB = b.subtract(a)
    // find angle between line's vector and x axis
    let angleRad = Math.atan2(vectorB.y, vectorB.x)
    if (angleRad < 0) {
      angleRad = 2 * Math.PI + angleRad
    }
    const angleDeg = fabric.util.radiansToDegrees(angleRad)
    // find initial horizontal position by rotating the tip back
    const c = fabric.util.rotatePoint(b.clone(), a, -angleRad)
    options = options || {}
    // finally, initialize using transform points to make a horizontal line
    this.callSuper('initialize', [a.x, a.y, c.x, c.y], {
      noScaleCache: false, // false to force cache update while scaling (doesn't redraw parts of line otherwise)
      selectable: true,
      evented: true, // true because you want to select line on click
      //minScaleLimit: 0.25, // has no effect now because we're resetting scale on each scale event
      lockRotation: false,
      hasRotatingPoint: false, // to disable rotation control
      centeredRotation: false,
      centeredScaling: false,
      
      originX: "left",    // origin of rotation/transformation.      
      originY: "bottom",    // origin of rotation/transformation.
      
      lockMovementX: true,
      lockMovementY: true,
      lockScalingFlip: true,
      lockScalingX: false,
      lockScalingY: false,
      lockSkewingX: false,
      lockSkewingY: false,
      lockUniScaling: true,
      ...options,
      angle: angleDeg // note that we use the calculated angle no matter what
    })
    
    this.setControlsVisibility({
        tr: false,
        tl: false,
        bl: false,
        mt: false, // middle top disable
        mb: false, // midle bottom
        ml: false, // middle left
        mr: false, // I think you get it
    })
    
    this.on('scaling', function (e) {
      // rotate to the pointer's x,y
      this.canvas._rotateObject(e.pointer.x, e.pointer.y)
      // while _rotateObject() tries to keep left/top at initial value,
      // it sometimes fails because of rounding errors (?)
      // so we need to do it manually again
      this.set({left: this.x1, top: this.y1})
      // calculate new length before resetting scale
      const xOffset = (this.x2 - this.x1) * this.scaleX
      const newLength = Math.max(this.minLength, xOffset)
      // reset scaleX/scaleY and set new x coord for the tip point
      this.set({
        scaleX: 1,
        scaleY: 1,
        x2: this.x1 + newLength
      })
    })
  }
})


const line1 = new fabric.RotatingLine([ 200, 200, 330, 200 ], {
  fill: 'red',
  stroke: 'red',
  strokeWidth: 3,
});

const line2 = new fabric.RotatingLine([ 200, 200, 100, 100 ], {
  fill: 'blue',
  stroke: 'blue',
  strokeWidth: 3,
});

canvas.add(line1, line2)

// Disables group selection.
canvas.on('selection:created', (e) => {
  if(e.target.type === 'activeSelection') {
    canvas.discardActiveObject();
  } else {
    //do nothing
  }
})

// Keeps objects inside canvas. undos move/rotate/scale out of canvas.
canvas.on('object:modified', function (options) {
    let obj = options.target;
    let boundingRect = obj.getBoundingRect(true);
    if (boundingRect.left < 0
        || boundingRect.top < 0
        || boundingRect.left + boundingRect.width > canvas.getWidth()
        || boundingRect.top + boundingRect.height > canvas.getHeight()) {
        obj.top = obj._stateProperties.top;
        obj.left = obj._stateProperties.left;
        obj.angle = obj._stateProperties.angle;
        obj.scaleX = obj._stateProperties.scaleX;
        obj.scaleY = obj._stateProperties.scaleY;
        obj.setCoords();
        obj.saveState();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.4.3/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id='c' width="500" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: Sorry I only just saw this now.   I already came up with another simple solution based on the stickman demo where line is redrawn whenever circle at endpoint is moved.  It works well for me.   The code snippet above gives a JS error when I try to run it, so I can't easily test.  Still, I appreciate the thought and effort that went into this answer, so I am selecting it as the answer.  thanks!!

Comment: @danda this is weird, I don't get any errors if I run the embedded snippet here. What's the error you're seeing?